# How to remove a node in a pointer to linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition

I'm trying to remove the last node of a linked list while returning its value. But all this pointers is confusing, like am I really removing it by calling p = NULL??

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};

/**
If list is empty, do nothing and return arbitrary value
otherwise, the last element in the list is removed and its value is returned.
**/
ElemType popBack(LIST *l) {
    NODE *p = l->front;
    NODE *previous = NULL;
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->next == NULL) {
            ElemType value = p->val;
            p = NULL;
            l->back = previous;
            return value;
        }
        previous = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return DEFAULT;
}
```

Comment: `p = NULL;` --> `previous->next = NULL;`

Comment: Why are you trying to delete the last element? Is it a Queue or Stack emulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters to use a singly-linked list to remove its last element is not an efficient approach. Instead you should use in this case a doubly-linked list.

Nevertheless in any case you need to free the memory occupied by the deleted node and correctly update not only the pointer `back` but also the pointer `front` of the list and the data member `next` of the pointer `previous`.

The function can look the following way

```
ElemType popBack( LIST *l)  
{
    ElemType value = DEFAULT;

    if ( l->front != NULL )
    {
        if ( l->front->next == NULL )
        {
            value = l->front->val;
            free( l->front );
            l->front = l->back = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            node *current = l->front;

            while ( current->next->next != NULL )
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        
            value = current->next->val;
        
            free( current->next );
            current->next = NULL;

            l->back = current;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```